# Is there a method in Expo to check if the device (phone or tablet) supports haptics and or vibration?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to notify user either with vibration or haptics using Expo and react-native.

The algorithm is roughly:

- if haptics is possible use haptics
- if haptics is not possible but vibration is possible then use vibration
- if none (for pads for example) is possible use none

The haptics and vibration of Expo works fine but I could not find out any method that informs if the haptics and vibration are usable with the current device.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer **NO**

I don't think that any phone which doesn't support vibration. Only phones which don't support vibration are simulators and emulators. Thats the reason I guess that there is no function to check it. As per RN documentation, If the phone doesn't support (eg. Simulator) the vibration function won't have any effect.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/vibration

Since, Vibration is the core module. Same applies to expo I guess.

Comment: Sriraman thanks for the answer, but for haptic, it is not supported by all devices. Similarly pads don’t have vibration either (I think I need to update subject line since it misleads to phone only approach).